# Bootstrap 5.3 Column Background Color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I need to color a table column background using Bootstrap. It was working before as follows:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-PI8n5gCcz9cQqQXm3PEtDuPG8qx9oFsFctPg0S5zb8g=" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="table-responsive mt-2">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">
    <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col class="table-info">
      <col>
    </colgroup>
    <thead class="text-center">
      <th scope="col">Blah</th>
      <th scope="col">Blah</th>
      <th scope="col">Blah</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="text-center">Blah</th>
      <td>Blah</td>
      <td>Blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="table-info">
      <th scope="row" class="text-center">Blah</th>
      <td>Blah</td>
      <td>Blah</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row" class="text-center">Blah</th>
      <td>Blah</td>
      <td>Blah</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The website was working before updating to Bootstrap 5.3.3.

I am using Bootstrap as:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-PI8n5gCcz9cQqQXm3PEtDuPG8qx9oFsFctPg0S5zb8g=" crossorigin="anonymous">
(...)
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vwkozhba/

The computed CSS shows the color:
[image]

Comment: So what is the difference between jsfiddle and your site? Please click [edit] and post a [mcve] here

Comment: @mplungjan I've just included the minimal reproducible example and the fiddle with the issue.

Comment: So I see in the snippet and the fiddle the blue background. So what is the issue, that it does not work on YOUR website or that it does not work with another bootstrap?

Comment: @mplungjan It shows the blue background for the row, not for the column.